# Repeating a previous line in a function until if statement is met

Tags: r

I would like to write an if statement that would continue to repeat a question until a certain condition is met

Something like this:

```
fun<-function(){
  x<-readline("what is x? ")
  if(x>5)
    {print("X must be less than 5")
    **repeat lines 3 & 4**
}else{
  print("Correct")}

}
```

Sorry for the **- but I'm not really sure how to correctly write that line. What I am looking to do is to have the prompt "what is x" repeated every time a number greater than 5 is inputted until a number less than five is given. In theory the function would look like this

```
fun()
what is x? 6
X must be less than 5
what is x? 8
X must be less than 5
what is x? 3
Correct
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`readline` returns a character vector, so you need to coerce it to numeric before the `if`.  Then you can use a `while` loop (as others have pointed out).

```
fun <- function() {
  x <- as.numeric(readline("what is x? "))
  if(is.na(x)) stop("x must be a number")
  while(x > 5) {
    print("X must be less than 5")
    x <- as.numeric(readline("what is x? "))
    if(is.na(x)) stop("x must be a number")
  }
  print("Correct")
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I'm not really sure of the language you're using, but something like a while loop should do it.

```
fun<-function(){
  x<-readline("what is x? ")
  while(x>5)
  {
    print("X must be less than 5")
    x<-readline("what is x? ")
  }
  print("Correct")}
}
```

Comment: +1 For correctly writing a `while` loop in a language you don't know.

Comment: Great guess, but `readline` returns a string, which makes the logical comparison fail.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the control structure `while` for this:

```
continue <- FALSE

while(!continue){
x<-readline("what is x? ")
  if(x>5){
    print("X must be less than 5")
  } else {
    continue <- TRUE
    print("Correct")
  }
}
```

For more detail, see `?"while"` or `?Control`

Answer (score 4):

Others mentioned `while`, you could also use `repeat` with the `if` condition calling `break`.  This can be used to create what other languages call an 'until' loop.

This feels a little more like what the question is asking than the `while` options (but it is mainly just a different syntax flavor, both will end up being equivalent programatically).